# Directory.Delete - how to tell if folder was not empty vs some other error?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, delete-directory

I'm trying to delete a folder only if it's not empty. So I'm using `Directory.Delete(strPath);` for that. It throws an exception if folder is not empty. But I can't seem to figure out how to differentiate between that error and some other error (say, if the path was wrong, folder didn't exist, was inaccessible because of ACL, etc.)

I can do this with Win32 in a heartbeat, but I'm somewhat stumped in .NET.

Any ideas?

```
try
{
    Directory.Delete(strPath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //if(FolderWasNotEmpty){ all-good-not-an-error(); }
    //else { show-error(); }
}
```

PS. I'm using `.NET 3.5` for this project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exception will include the Win32 error code, or will be a subclass that indicates what type of exception was thrown. Inspect the value of `ex` at runtime and see what you can determine from it

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson: There's a private (or protected) `HResult` in the `Exception` but I can't access it. I can only see it with a debugger.

Comment: Oh `HResult` wasn't made public until later versions of .Net. Try [Marshal.GetHRForException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethrforexception?view=netframework-3.5)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson: OK, Good deal, thanks.